# Placing SVG/Image code into </style>

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to figure out how I would put this code into`</style>`, can someone help me with this.

I'm thinking what you could do is, put as much of it into `</style>` and then I'll see what I want to keep there.

Can someone help me do this, **none of the answers below helped.**

https://jsfiddle.net/sasyk9td/2/

```html
<svg width="260" height="194">
  <defs>
    <clippath id="circleView">
      <circle cx="130" cy="97" r="85" fill="orange"></circle>
    </clippath>
  </defs>
  <image x="40" y="7" width="180" height="180" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)"></image>
  <image x="40" y="7" width="180" height="180" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: what do u want exactly?

Comment: Do you want to put most of your styling code to <style> tag rather than in the body part?

Answer (score 0):

styling can be happened in 3 ways.

1. inline styling
2. internal styling (usning `</style>` tab in head section)
3. external styling (create external style sheet ans link in html page)

You can put re-usable styles in `</style>` tag called internal styling. Maximum optimisation can be done here. please check.

```
<style>
   svg { width: 260px; height: 194; }
   image { width: 180px; height: 180px; }
</style>

<svg>
   <defs>
      <clippath id="circleView">
         <circle cx="130" cy="97" r="85" fill="orange"></circle>
      </clippath>
   </defs>
   <image x="40" y="7" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)">
   </image>
   <image x="40" y="7" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: could you please change the x value a bit and check and also change the width for the image tag of second one

Comment: for me showing proper values without changing the code. share me your mail id or  something i will share screenshot.